# Creating a multi array from json file value

Tags: javascript, json

i have this json file named data.json and I can not write a for cycle  to have returned an array like this

> var arr=[["CR7012","",100,1,100],[CR7012,"bla bla
>   bla",100,5,500],["CR7012,"bla bla bla",100,1,100]]

data.json

> {
>     "prodotti": [
>       {
>         "articolo": "CR7012",
>         "descrizione": "",
>         "prezzo": 100,
>         "quantita": "1",
>         "totale": 100
>       },
>       {
>         "articolo": "CR7012",
>         "descrizione": "bla bla bla",
>         "prezzo": 100,
>         "quantita": "5",
>         "totale": 500
>       },
>       {
>         "articolo": "CR7012",
>         "descrizione": "bla bla bla",
>         "prezzo": 100,
>         "quantita": "1",
>         "totale": 100
>       }
>     ],
>   }

thanks to all those who will help me

Comment: why can't you write the for loop ? show us what you tried so far.

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("./tmp/data.json", function(data) {
                $.each(data.prodotti, function(key, value){
                    var arr = [];
                        var po = [value.descrizione, value.prezzo, value.quantita, value.totale];
                        arr.push(po).toString();
                        });
        });
    });
```

and the variable arr, I included it in

> var body = [arr]

for make a table in pdfmake, but unfortunately it gives me back an error.